# How to add different values in same TextView in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

A want to develop a project in android using SOAP service protocol. So that i get XML and parse it into String array. I want to show one String (Like String[0]) in one TextView then when a user click the next button next String (Like String[1]) will show on the same page and the same TextView. How how could i do that?

Comment: Changing the contents of a TextView is perhaps the second thing you would learn from a HelloWorld tutorial. I don't mean to be harsh but if you don't know how to do this then you should really go and follow a few of those. You can't expect to come here for every help with every third line of code moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you do not know much of android.

in your main activity class where you want to show data create the filed String array as

```
public class NNN extends Activity {
//... some other fields

private String[] data;
private int current;
Private TextView yourTextView;

//in on create
data = null;
current = 0;
yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

then in the method where you parsed the XML of string array do

```
data = parsedArray;
current =0;
```

then on button click where you want to set the text to text view

```
if(data ! = null) {
    //means you have parsed XML to string array
    if(current != data.length) {
        //means there is some data that user did not viewd
        youTextView.setText(data[current]);
        current++;
    }
}
```

You must see some tutorials to get familiar to the android. See [Creating hello world app](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the SOAP architecture. But I will assume you store the strings parsed as following array. And also we must keep track of the current displaying string:

```
static String[] myparsedarray;
static int curIndex;
```

add an OnClickListener to your 'next' button:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    //your string array
    static String[] myparsedarray;
    static int curIndex;
       .
       .
       .   //lots of other code

       // inside onCreate()
       public void onCreate(...) {
           Button nextBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
           nextBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                   TextView myloopingtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
                   curIndex = (curIndex + 1) % myparsedarray.length;
                   //the modulus to avoid arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :)
                   myloopingtext.setText(myparsedarray[curIndex]);
               }
           });
          .
          .
          .   //rest of the code
       }
}
```

P.S others: Correct me if I am wrong :)

edit: As indivisible said, look into android tutorials. I also suggest you search for similar questions. Cheers!

Comment: you are having 2d array. but on `setText` .. Ops